# Proper way to handle Default DNS warning when switching to reactive

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

After switching from `quarkus-rest-client` to `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`

A warning started appearing.

```
WARN  [io.net.res.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider]  (Quarkus Main Thread) Default DNS servers: [/8.8.8.8:53, /8.8.4.4:53] (Google Public DNS as a fallback)
```

What I've found so far is that it's related to a change on Quarkus 2.7 that disables JNDI by default due to security reasons.

What's the proper way to handle the warning? I don't want it to appear (or at least not as warning) but to keep the security meassures. Does it mean the app will fail if it is deployed to a cluster without access to internet?

Java: 11
Quarkus: 2.12.3.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what changed (runtime environment or Quarkus code), but on Quarkus 2.16.7.Final the warning no longer appears.

- `compiler-plugin.version`: 3.10.1
- `maven.compiler.release`: 17
- `quarkus.platform.artifact-id`: quarkus-bom
- `quarkus.platform.group-id`: io.quarkus.platform
- `quarkus.platform.version`: 2.16.7.Final